# What regex will match 4 digits, a period, then one and only one digit?

Tags: java, regex

I need a (Java) regular expression that will match:

```
XXXX.X
```

Where X is any number, only one number after the decimal point.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try `^\d{4}\.\d$` if you want the entire string to match, remove the `^` and/or `$` if you want it to find matches within a larger string.

If there can be any number of integers before the `.` use `\d+` instead of `\d{4}` to match one or more, or `\d*` to match zero or more (the string `".5"` would match `\d*\.\d`).

Comment: `\d` means digit, it's like `[0-9]` and `{4}` is "repeat 4" (assuming your regexp engine supports it).  You could go back to basics and use `^[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]\.[0-9]$`

Comment: what should be the regular experssion for: xxxx-xxxx?

Answer (score 0):

If the number is exactly 4 digits,then try this

```
"/(^([0-9]{4})[.]([0-9]{1})$)/"
```

Eg : 1234.4

Or if the number is of unlimited digits,try this..

```
"/(^([0-9]{0,})[.]([0-9]{1})$)/"
```

Eg: 1234.4
    45.8
    589745324744.7